# Determine the language describe by the CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar, dfa, context-free-language

```
S -> 1A
A -> 0B | 1A | epsilon
B -> 0C | 1B
C -> 0A | 1C
```

I was thinking that the language described by this grammar is the following:
L = {0,1 | w string contains 1+ OR it has at least three 0's}

Does this seem correct?

Comment: No, that's wrong. If this language contains a zero, it has to consume at least two more zeros. Ergo, the number of zeros is a multiple of three, not at least three.

Answer (score 0):

It is a regular CFG so its DFA given below:
[image]

It is a language that consist of alphabet =`{0,1}` this language accept one `1` or multiple `1`'s.if `0` input it need 3`(0)` to go to final.between this multiple `1` come after every `0.`